# questions about colab and colab-pro?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a few questions about colab
1) how many session I can start with one google account colab/colab-pro?
2) is it possible to login multiple google account in one computer and use colab/colab-pro?

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer to the second question. I've just checked and there is no problem to login into multiple google accounts and create a collab kernel for each.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you can use two GPUs simultaneously—one with regular RAM and the other with High-RAM. Google allocates credits to you for using different GPU types, and each type of GPU consumes a certain amount of credits per hour, which you can view. When your credits run out, you can only use the T4 GPU.